# Firebase Data Retrieval Error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to store values of all nodes in a class but it seems like it isn't storing it in class. Can't figure out the probable correction in the readDataListener(). As you can see I'm trying to store the values of all nodes in a class but don't know what I'm getting wrong.

**SymptomActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class SymptomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
Button button;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_symptom);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);


    // Write a message to the database
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // store app title to 'app_title' node
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("app_title").setValue("microDoctor");
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("symptomList");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.child("Headache").child("Some Value").setValue("Head");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.setValue("Headache");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            readDataListener();
        }
    });
}

private void readDataListener() {
    mFirebaseDatabase.child("Abdominal Cramps").child("Diarrhea").child("Vomiting").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Symptom symptom = dataSnapshot.getValue(Symptom.class);

            // Check for null
            if (symptom == null) {
                Log.e("Data", "Symptom data is null!");
                return;
            }

            Log.e("Symptom Data", "User data is changed!"+symptom.symptom1);

            // Display newly updated name and email
            textView.setText(symptom.disease);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });
}}
```

**Symptom.java**
public class Symptom {

```
public String symptom1;
public String symptom2;
public String symptom3;
public String disease;

// Default constructor required for calls to
// DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
public Symptom(){

}
public  Symptom(String symptom1, String symptom2, String symptom3, String disease){
    this.symptom1 = symptom1;
    this.symptom2 = symptom2;
    this.symptom3 = symptom3;
    this.disease = disease;
}
}
```

**Data Trying to Access**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to get data under a node that is not present in your model class file. So `Vomiting` could not be mapped. Assuming that `app_title` is a direct child of your Firebase root, you can simply use `String class` to get that value like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("app_title").child("microDoctor").child("symptomList").child("Abdominal Cramps").child("Diarrhea").child("Vomiting");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String disease = ds.child("disease").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", disease);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
Food Poisoning
```

Also you need to add the public setter and getter in your model class for your field like this:

```
public class Symptom {
    public String disease;

    public Symptom(){}

    public Symptom(String disease){
        this.disease = disease;
    }

    public String getDisease(){
        return disease;
    }
    public void setDisease(String disease){
        this.disease=disease;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed some code. Also, now I'm able to access it but now the task is to store all the values of nodes in class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Symptom {
public String disease;

// Default constructor required for calls to
// DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
public Symptom(){

}
public  Symptom(String disease){
this.disease = disease;
}

 public String getDisease(){
 return disease;
}
  public void setDisease(String disease){
    this.disease=disease;
}
      }
```

Comment: That's not correct because `Vomiting` is not a field in his model class is actually a node. Is the parent of `disease` child. Please see the actual screenshot that was provided by the OP.

Comment: Changed some part of code and also the task in hand now.